# Int to Float conversion Python to C++

Tags: python, c++, floating-point, integer, bit

I have a function written in Python that works perfectly for what I need(it wasn't written by me).
I need to convert it to C++ so that it provides the same outcome. I know that it saves that float into 16-bit texture, so I am guessing this is converting 32-bit int into 16-bit float. All I need to to is to make it work in C++. Here is the python function:

```
def packTextureBits(index):
    index = int(index)
    index = index +1024
    sigh=index&0x8000
    sigh=sigh<<16
    exptest=index&0x7fff
    if exptest==0:
        exp=0
    else:
        exp=index>>10
        exp=exp&0x1f
        exp=exp-15
        exp=exp+127
        exp=exp<<23
    mant=index&0x3ff
    mant=mant<<13
    index=sigh|exp|mant
    
    cp = pointer(c_int(index))
    fp = cast(cp, POINTER(c_float))
    return fp.contents.value
```

This was my approach in C++, but it returns completely screwed up values:

```
float PackIntToFloat(int value)
{
    value += 1024;
    int sign = (value & 0x8000) << 16;
    int exp = value & 0x7fff;
    if(exp != 0)
    {
        exp = value >> 10;
        exp = exp & 0x1f;
        exp = exp - 15 + 127;
        exp = exp << 23;
    }
    int mant = (value & 0x3fff) << 13;
    value = sign | exp | mant;

    int* cp = new int(value);
    float* fp = reinterpret_cast<float*>(cp);

    return *fp;
    // Also tried return (float)value; but returns other weird values.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found that topic and a few more before, none of the solutions there gave the same outcome as this python thing. Far from that. My issue is also that my knowledge is not that much low level, and I don't 100% know if that conversion you posted is actually the same thing as that python conversion.

Comment: I do not know what kind of int is incoming there, because python doesn't even specify what type that is, but on the top of that python function it goes ```index = int(index);``` and I assume that int in python is just 32-bit signed int. So basically what I would need is signed int 32 to float 16 conversion.

Comment: I know what code that calls it does. This code in python comes from Blender plugin for UE4. Basically what happens there is,  the blender code takes all 3d objects, indexes them from 0 to whatever number of objects there is - that's never below 0. These indexes are then injected into this function, and value returned is saved to the texture alpha channel. One object is one pixel that has its own alpha. Which happens to be HDR 16-bit texture. Then in UE4 material function reverts that process on alpha of each pixel of this texture. That reverting code is done in HLSL.

Comment: I have my own 3d-like tool in UE4 that I created as a plugin. But this one is written in C++. And my meshes are also indexes from 0-to whatever. And I am trying to reproduce this function and write it to texture the same way.

Comment: Well, thing is that might not work. First of all texture type that is required for this operation is FloatRGBA. Not U16. And secondly, red, green and blue channels are populated with position of the said object in 3D space and those are three floats. And they weren't meant to be converted. At least in the original plugin.

Comment: This is all a bit unclear to me. (The reason might be that I'm not familiar with UE4.)

Comment: That's the bit that reverts this python thing later on in HLSL:

```uint uRes32 = asuint(N);

const uint sign2 = ((uRes32>>16)&0x8000);
const uint exp2  = ((((const int) ((uRes32>>23)&0xff))-127+15) << 10);
const uint mant2 = ((uRes32>>13)&0x3ff);
const uint bits = (sign2 | exp2 | mant2);
const uint result = bits - 1024;
return float(result);```

Comment: Can you demonstrate how "it does not work"? I.e., provide an example input with an expected output (also explain, why you expect that output).

Comment: Yeah. So I am inputing index as simple number 1. Save it to texture the python way. Then use HLSL to decode it, and I get 1 again. 
Then I use C++ version also inputing 1 into it, saving it to the texture, and the exact same decode hlsl code outputs 15338.0285.

Comment: Please condense this to a [mre] in the question itself. Don't hide relevant information inside the comments.

Comment: This looks like a typo compared to the python version: `int mant = (value & 0x3fff) << 13;`

Comment: Indeed, that was a typo, but that wasn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So I owe you apologize guys. I was being stupid, not doing enough tests before posting here. My C++ solution is 100% working. I tested separate colors of the texture, and as it turned out, I assigned values to the texture the wrong way. I tried pushing floats into the texture, and it was 16 bit texture. I needed to convert these floats into half-precision floats after this conversion above, and then it started working. Texture flag called PF_FloatRGBA led me into believing that floats were the right thing to assign there, and they werent.

I still need to learn a lot. Thanks for all your help!